# Gitlab pipeline doesn't fetch image from private repository at docker hub

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have a task to use a custom docker image to run the job inside it from *private* docker repository from Docker hub.

I faced an issue that following Gitlab guidance:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#determine-your-docker_auth_config-data

I put a *non-protected* variable `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` as a group level variable as follows with the body:

```json
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.hub.docker.com": {
            "auth": "my-base64-creds"
        }
    }
}
```

In my Gitlab pipeline template file I had like:

```yaml
image: mynamespace/image-name:my-image-tag
```

But it kept failing with:

```
ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "mynamespace/image-name:my-image-tag" with specified policies [always]: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for mynamespace/image-name, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied (manager.go:203:0s)
```

Comment: I had left the default of _protected_ variable `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` -- very helpful to have a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to define the registry host **explicitly**, like:

```yaml
image: registry.hub.docker.com/mynamespace/image-name:my-image-tag
```

I assumed that Docker Hub is a default hub as usual, but apparently it's some misconfiguration inside and letting it know explicitly fixes the problem